# Select and add Element but only if certain Tag not exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery Upload. When 1 Image is uploaded, this Image is automatically the Default Image. The Word "Main" shows up under this Image. When you upload a second Image, I of course want that the Text "Set as Main" shows up under this second Image. With the Code below, it will of course show up under the second, but also additional under the first Image. I do understand why, it makes sense, but I don't want it to happen. How can I now filter out if there is already the  Tag there, leave it, if there is not, add the new Tag. Can anyone give me a Hint how to solve this?

```
  if ($('#default').val() == '')
  {   
    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').after('<h6 class="default">Main</h6>'); 
  }
  else{
    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').after('<h6 class="setDefault">Set as Main</h6>');
  }
```

Comment: i assume you'll be able to upload as many images you want? So you could have 6 images and the 4th is set as the main image?

Answer (score 1):

I would on page add a class to the current selected main image. Which you have with class default. Then on click of the current '.setDefault' i would remove default replace this with 'setDefault' and also edit the text. Then on the currently selected link change the class and also change the text. Something like this:

```
$('.setDefault').click(function(){
    $('.default').removeClass('default').addClass('default').text('Set as Main')
    $(this).removeClass('setDefault').addClass('default').text('Main')
});
```

Now just incorporate this into your current code.

edit:

```
if ($('#default').val() == '')
{   
     $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').first().after('<h6 class="default">Main</h6>'); 
}
else{
    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').eq(1).after('<h6 class="setDefault">Set as Main</h6>');
}
```

eq being the secrect here then. The trouble i see with this is, eq is a hard set value. It will also apply to the 2nd a here. If you really are only using this code when you ahve first created an album and uploading a second this should be fine. Then with the original JavaScript taking over. 
Sorry if this doesn't help

Comment: I have something similar already when you click on the Image, but right now I am just looking for the situation that when an Image gets uploaded, the first is "Main" automatically and the next uploaded "Set as Main"

Comment: Mmh, no, again, Text only under the first Image and nothing under the second. Thank you so much for trying. There must be a way...

Comment: Do me a favour and run this in the console and tell me what it returns:    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').eq(1) also no worries, i'm just sitting here waiting for 5:30 :p

Comment: :) I am off a little bit earlier, so I have to leave it for today. Thanks a lot for your help. Have to get back to this again tomorrow, maybe I can can than find a solution. Thanks again and maybe u are back on as well tomorrow?

Comment: ye why not, shouldn't be to difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var $a = $('a.ui-icon-zoomin:last');
  if ($('#default').val() == '')
  {   
      if($a.next('h6').length == 0){
         $a.after('<h6 class="default">Main</h6>'); 
      }
  }
  else{
      if($a.next('h6').length == 0){
         $a.after('<h6 class="setDefault">Set as Main</h6>');
      }
  }
```

Comment: Close. Now it will only show "Main" under the first image, but I want "Set as Main" under the second Image to show up, which it does not do right now. Any idea?

Comment: thank you, but still nothing, no Text under the second Image.

Answer (score 0):

If you adding images after each other then you may want do this:

```
  if ($('#default').val() == '')
  {   
    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').after('<h6 class="default">Main</h6>'); 
  }
  else{
    $('a.ui-icon-zoomin').last().after('<h6 class="setDefault">Set as Main</h6>');
  }
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: No, unfortunately I than get on the first Image "Main" and "Set as Main" and on the second Image nothing.